# touch event frequency on android tablets vs. smartphone

Tags: android, tablet, touchscreen

I have written a simple Android application with a view which overrides onTouchEvent().

I am counting the ACTION_MOVE events and receive roughly 60 events per second on a smartphone (Nexus s) when I move my finger pretty fast but only 20 events per second on Xoom tablet or 30 events per second on Asus transformer, which are both much stronger than the smartphone.

Is it possible to query the ACTION_MOVE events on the tablets at a higher rate, at least as fast as the smartphone counterpart?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have any specific evidence, but my guess is that you are at the mercy of the hardware. And the touch sensors on the tablets just may not be capable of sending the events as fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving to openGL solved my problems

Answer (score 0):

That really depends on the touchscreen (and the lowlevel driver) your device manufacturer has built into your device. Android just sits on top of the touchscreen driver and takes the touch-events your touchscreen produces. There might be some filtering in the driver but there is afaik no rule / limit for event speed.

Bad touchscreens with a bad resolution (which is independant of your pixel resolution) will usually generate less events since they can't detect so much movement. Also some touchscreens may produce `ACTION_MOVE` event although you did not move your finger.